# Permission error while configure Chrome Remote Desktop to use Xfce by default

Tags: permissions, remote-desktop, google-compute-engine, debian-stretch

I'm trying to [setting up Chrome Remote Desktop](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#connecting_to_the_vm_instance) on my VM instance (*Debian GNU/Linux, 9 (stretch), amd64*) on Google cloud. I tried to install [Xfce](https://www.xfce.org/) as desktop environment. I installed Xfce component successfully with these command.

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt install --assume-yes xfce4 desktop-base
```

But I'm getting permission error even using ***sudo*** with this command.

```
echo "exec /usr/bin/xfce4-session" > /etc/chrome-remote-desktop-session
```

So, I'm stucked in the middle of the proccess. 
Here is the screenshot of the terminal.
[image: terminal screenshot]

Also I tried with [Cinnamon](https://www.linuxmint.com/) but same permission error is showing in the same command.

```
sudo echo "exec /usr/bin/cinnamon-session-cinnamon2d" > /etc/chrome-remote-desktop-session
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I was setting up Chrome Remote Desktop on a VM instance. However, as [**Google documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#installing_an_x_windows_system_desktop_environment) states:

> You might see a Permission Denied error for the update-initramfs process during installation. This is normal, and you can ignore the error.

In this situation, just proceed to the next step and it should work for you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But in the documentation, this statement regarding on the first step,I believe.

Comment: Hello Kiran,  
In order to replicate the issue, I have followed the [article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#installing_an_x_windows_system_desktop_environment) again and confirm that the error occurs during the 2nd step, after running:  

`echo "exec /usr/bin/xfce4-session" > /etc/chrome-remote-desktop-session`  

However, after continuing with the next steps, I was able complete the setup successfully.  

Please proceed to the next step of the tutorial.